# Unable to enumerate usb device whenever it is connected while my application is running

Tags: android, usb, enumeration

I am building an app for UsbInterfacing and i need to enumerate usb devices continously while my application is running..i need to be notified when it is connected and disconnected.. My usb device's vendor id is 1204 and product-id is 64905..The enumeration works once. Will not work after i unplug the device and plug it back in..Below is my code:

```
        package com.example.enumerate; 

        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
        import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;

        public class Enumerate extends Activity {

            UsbDevice device;
            Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

            }
//My onResume method
            @Override
            protected void onResume() 
            {
                super.onResume();
                UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
                deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
             //my UsbIterator    
            while(deviceIterator.hasNext())
            {
                    device = deviceIterator.next(); 
            }
                if(device.getProductId()==64905) //my device ProductId
                {
                    Toast t=Toast.makeText(this,"Connected",2000);
                    t.show();

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast t=Toast.makeText(this,"Not Connected",2000);
                }
                }


        }
```

Comment: Aside from the fact your code is backwards (most people put `onCreate` before `onResume` for better readability) - you're only checking for the USB devices once during `onResume`. You need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for the various Broadcast Actions sent by the system when devices are attached or detached. The UsbManager docs show the various action constants.

Comment: How do i use a BroadcastReceiver to listen for different actions?? Could you give an example code?

Comment: OK. I've posted a basic template for doing what you needed to do (it also serves as a basic template for any `BroadcastReceiver` and `Activity` setup). Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a BroadcastReceiver to listen for the various Broadcast Actions sent by the system when devices are attached or detached. The UsbManager docs show the various action constants.

A basic template `Activity` with inner `BroadcastReceiver` class might look like this...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    MyReceiver myReceiver = null;
    IntentFilter intentFilter = null;
    boolean isReceiverRegistered = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        // Add any or all of the following 'actions' to the IntentFilter
        // depending on what you need to track.
        intentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED);
        intentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);
        intentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        intentFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!isReceiverRegistered) {
            myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
            isReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (isReceiverRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
            myReceiver = null;
            isReceiverRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        protected void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action, accessory, device, permissionGranted;

            action = intent.getAction();

            // Make sure you check to see if any of the strings are null
            // just in case the Intent isn't carrying any of them
            accessory = intent.getStringExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
            device = intent.getStringExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            permissionGranted = intent.getStringExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);

            // Do what you need to do based on the action and extras...
        }
    }
}
```